# Tex \implies symbol does not work

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

I needed couple of times to use the \implies symbol (which is basically a double lined right arrow). It works in Mathoverflow.net, but here it doesn't work: $\implies$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$\Rightarrow$`: $\Rightarrow$

Answer (score 12):

You no longer need this, as the [AMSsymbol extension has been enabled](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/please-enable-amssymbols-extension-for-mathjax).

---

`\implies` requires the AMSsymbol extension which is not enabled. But many symbols have a replacement, or you could directly put a Unicode symbol.

The following shows a list of unsupported AMSsymbol symbols, and their replacements,

```
\digamma  = ϝ  or  &#x3dd;
\varkappa = ϰ  or  &#x3f0;

\varGamma   = \mathit\Gamma
\varDelta   = \mathit\Delta
\varTheta   = \mathit\Theta
\varLambda  = \mathit\Lambda
\varXi      = \mathit\Xi
\varPi      = \mathit\Pi
\varSigma   = \mathit\Sigma
\varUpsilon = \mathit\Upsilon
\varPhi     = \mathit\Phi
\varPsi     = \mathit\Psi
\varOmega   = \mathit\Omega

\beth   = ℶ  or  &#x2136;
\gimel  = ℷ  or  &#x2137;
\daleth = ℸ  or  &#x2138;

\backprime         = ‵  or  &#x2035;
\hslash            = \unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x210f}
\varnothing        = \unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x2205}
\blacktriangle     = ▲  or  &#x25b2;
\triangledown      = \unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x25bd}
\blacktriangledown = ▼  or  &#x25bc;
\square            = □  or  &#x25a1;
\Box               = □  or  &#x25a1;
\blacksquare       = ■  or  &#x25a0;
\lozenge           = ◊  or  &loz;
\Diamond           = ◊  or  &loz;
\blacklozenge      = ⧫  or  &#x29eb;
\circledS          = Ⓢ  or  &#x24c8;
\bigstar           = ★  or  &#x2605;  or  {\Large\star}
\sphericalangle    = ∢  or  &#x2222;
\measuredangle     = ∡  or  &#x2221;
\nexists           = ∄  or  &#x2204;
\complement        = ∁  or  &#x2201;
\mho               = ℧  or  &#x2127;
\eth               = ð  or  &eth;
\Finv              = Ⅎ  or  &#x2132;
\diagup            = ╱  or  &#x2571;
\Game              = ⅁  or  &#x2141;
\diagdown          = ╲  or  &#x2572;
\Bbbk              = \mathbb{k}

\yen       = ¥  or  &yen;
\circledR  = ®  or  &reg;
\checkmark = ✓  or  &#x2713;
\maltese   = ✠  or  &#x2720;

\dotplus         = ∔  or  &#x2214;  or  \mathrel{\dot+}
\ltimes          = ⋉  or  &#x22c9;
\smallsetminus   = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x2216}}
\rtimes          = ⋊  or  &#x22ca;
\Cap             = ⋒  or  &#x22d2;
\doublecap       = ⋒  or  &#x22d2;
\leftthreetimes  = ⋋  or  &#x22cb;
\Cup             = ⋓  or  &#x22d3;
\doublecup       = ⋓  or  &#x22d3;
\rightthreetimes = ⋌  or  &#x22cc;
\barwedge        = ⊼  or  &#x22bc;  or  \mathrel{\bar\wedge}
\curlywedge      = ⋏  or  &#x22cf;
\veebar          = ⊻  or  &#x22bb;
\curlyvee        = ⋎  or  &#x22ce;
\doublebarwedge  = ⩞  or  &#x2a5e;  or  \mathrel{\bar{\bar\wedge}}
\boxminus        = ⊟  or  &#x229f;
\circleddash     = ⊝  or  &#x229d;
\boxtimes        = ⊠  or  &#x22a0;
\circledast      = ⊛  or  &#x229b;
\boxdot          = ⊡  or  &#x22a1;
\circledcirc     = ⊚  or  &#x229a;
\boxplus         = ⊞  or  &#x229e;
\centerdot       = \cdot  or  &#x22c5;
\divideontimes   = ⋇  or  &#x22c7;
\intercal        = ⊺  or  &#x22ba;

\leqq               = ≦  or  &#x2266;
\geqq               = ≧  or  &#x2267;
\leqslant           = ⩽  or  &#x2a7d;
\geqslant           = ⩾  or  &#x2a7e;
\eqslantless        = ⪕  or  &#x2a95;
\eqslantgtr         = ⪖  or  &#x2a96;
\lesssim            = ≲  or  &#x2272;
\gtrsim             = ≳  or  &#x2273;
\lessapprox         = ⪅  or  &#x2a85;
\gtrapprox          = ⪆  or  &#x2a86;
\approxeq           = ≊  or  &#x224a;
\lessdot            = ⋖  or  &#x22d6;
\gtrdot             = ⋗  or  &#x22d7;
\lll                = ⋘  or  &#x22d8;
\llless             = ⋘  or  &#x22d8;
\ggg                = ⋙  or  &#x22d9;
\gggtr              = ⋙  or  &#x22d9;
\lessgtr            = ≶  or  &#x2276;
\gtrless            = ≷  or  &#x2277;
\lesseqgtr          = ⋚  or  &#x22da;
\gtreqless          = ⋛  or  &#x22db;
\lesseqqgtr         = ⪋  or  &#x2a8b;
\gtreqqless         = ⪌  or  &#x2a8c;
\doteqdot           = ≑  or  &#x2251;
\Doteq              = ≑  or  &#x2251;
\eqcirc             = ≖  or  &#x2256;
\risingdotseq       = ≓  or  &#x2253;
\circeq             = ≗  or  &#x2257;
\fallingdotseq      = ≒  or  &#x2252;
\triangleq          = ≜  or  &#x225c;
\backsim            = ∽  or  &#x223d;
\thicksim           = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x223c}}
\backsimeq          = ⋍  or  &#x22cd;
\thickapprox        = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x2248}}
\subseteqq          = ⫅  or  &#x2ac5;
\supseteqq          = ⫆  or  &#x2ac6;
\Subset             = ⋐  or  &#x22d0;
\Supset             = ⋑  or  &#x22d1;
\sqsubset           = ⊏  or  &#x228f;
\sqsupset           = ⊐  or  &#x2290;
\preccurlyeq        = ≼  or  &#x227c;
\succcurlyeq        = ≽  or  &#x227d;
\curlyeqprec        = ⋞  or  &#x22de;
\curlyeqsucc        = ⋟  or  &#x22df;
\precsim            = ≾  or  &#x227e;
\succsim            = ≿  or  &#x227f;
\precapprox         = ⪷  or  &#x2ab7;
\succapprox         = ⪸  or  &#x2ab8;
\vartriangleleft    = ⊲  or  &#x22b2;
\lhd                = ⊲  or  &#x22b2;
\vartriangleright   = ⊳  or  &#x22b3;
\rhd                = ⊳  or  &#x22b3;
\trianglelefteq     = ⊴  or  &#x22b4;
\unlhd              = ⊴  or  &#x22b4;
\trianglerighteq    = ⊵  or  &#x22b5;
\unrhd              = ⊵  or  &#x22b5;
\vDash              = ⊨  or  &#x22a8;
\Vdash              = ⊩  or  &#x22a9;
\Vvdash             = ⊪  or  &#x22aa;
\smallsmile         = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x2323}}
\shortmid           = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x2223}}
\smallfrown         = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x2322}}
\shortparallel      = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x2225}}
\bumpeq             = ≏  or  &#x224f;
\between            = ≬  or  &#x226c;
\Bumpeq             = ≎  or  &#x224e;
\pitchfork          = ⋔  or  &#x22d4;
\varpropto          = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x221d}}
\backepsilon        = ∍  or  &#x220d;
\blacktriangleleft  = ◀  or  &#x25c0;
\blacktriangleright = ▶  or  &#x25b6;
\therefore          = ∴  or  &there4;
\because            = ∵  or  &#x2235;
\eqsim              = ≂  or  &#x2242;
\vartriangle        = \mathrel{\unicode[MathJax_AMS]{x25b3}}
\Join               = ⋈  or  &#x22c8;

\nless            = ≮  or  &#x226e;  or  \not<
\ngtr             = ≯  or  &#x226f;  or  \not>
\nleq             = ≰  or  &#x2270;  or  \not\le
\ngeq             = ≱  or  &#x2271;  or  \not\ge
\nleqslant        = \mathrel&#xe010;  or  \not&#x2a7d;
\ngeqslant        = \mathrel&#xe00f;  or  \not&#x2a7e;
\nleqq            = \mathrel&#xe011;  or  \not&#x2266;
\ngeqq            = \mathrel&#xe00e;  or  \not&#x2267;
\lneq             = ⪇  or  &#x2a87;
\gneq             = ⪈  or  &#x2a88;
\lneqq            = ≨  or  &#x2268;
\gneqq            = ≩  or  &#x2269;
\lvertneqq        = \mathrel&#xe00c;
\gvertneqq        = \mathrel&#xe00d;
\lnsim            = ⋦  or  &#x22e6;
\gnsim            = ⋧  or  &#x22e7;
\lnapprox         = ⪉  or  &#x2a89;
\gnapprox         = ⪊  or  &#x2a8a;
\nprec            = ⊀  or  &#x2280;  or  \not\prec
\nsucc            = ⊁  or  &#x2281;  or  \not\succ
\npreceq          = ⋠  or  &#x22e0;  or  \not\preceq
\nsucceq          = ⋡  or  &#x22e1;  or  \not\succeq
\precneqq         = ⪵  or  &#x2ab5;
\succneqq         = ⪶  or  &#x2ab6;
\precnsim         = ⋨  or  &#x22e8;
\succnsim         = ⋩  or  &#x22e9;
\precnapprox      = ⪹  or  &#x2ab9;
\succnapprox      = ⪺  or  &#x2aba;
\nsim             = ≁  or  &#x2241;
\ncong            = ≆  or  &#x2246;  or  \not\cong
\nshortmid        = \mathrel&#xe006;
\nshortparallel   = \mathrel&#xe007;
\nmid             = ∤  or  &#x2224;
\nparallel        = ∦  or  &#x2226;
\nvdash           = ⊬  or  &#x22ac;
\nvDash           = ⊭  or  &#x22ad;
\nVdash           = ⊮  or  &#x22ae;
\nVDash           = ⊯  or  &#x22af;
\ntriangleleft    = ⋪  or  &#x22ea;
\ntriangleright   = ⋫  or  &#x22eb;
\ntrianglelefteq  = ⋬  or  &#x22ec;
\ntrianglerighteq = ⋭  or  &#x22ed;
\nsubseteq        = ⊈  or  &#x2288;  or  \not\subseteq
\nsupseteq        = ⊉  or  &#x2289;  or  \not\supseteq
\nsubseteqq       = \mathrel&#xe016;  or  \not&#x2ac5;
\nsupseteqq       = \mathrel&#xe018;  or  \not&#x2ac6;
\subsetneq        = ⊊  or  &#x228a;
\supsetneq        = ⊋  or  &#x228b;
\varsubsetneq     = \mathrel&#xe01a;
\varsupsetneq     = \mathrel&#xe01b;
\subsetneqq       = ⫋  or  &#x2acb;
\supsetneqq       = ⫌  or  &#x2acc;
\varsubsetneqq    = \mathrel&#xe017;
\varsupsetneqq    = \mathrel&#xe019;

\leftleftarrows      = ⇇  or  &#x21c7;
\rightrightarrows    = ⇉  or  &#x21c9;
\leftrightarrows     = ⇆  or  &#x21c6;
\rightleftarrows     = ⇄  or  &#x21c4;
\Lleftarrow          = ⇚  or  &#x21da;
\Rrightarrow         = ⇛  or  &#x21db;
\twoheadleftarrow    = ↞  or  &#x219e;
\twoheadrightarrow   = ↠  or  &#x21a0;
\leftarrowtail       = ↢  or  &#x21a2;
\rightarrowtail      = ↣  or  &#x21a3;
\looparrowleft       = ↫  or  &#x21ab;
\looparrowright      = ↬  or  &#x21ac;
\leftrightharpoons   = ⇋  or  &#x21cb;
\rightleftharpoons   = ⇌  or  &#x21cc;
\curvearrowleft      = ↶  or  &#x21b6;
\curvearrowright     = ↷  or  &#x21b7;
\circlearrowleft     = ↺  or  &#x21ba;
\circlearrowright    = ↻  or  &#x21bb;
\Lsh                 = ↰  or  &#x21b0;
\Rsh                 = ↱  or  &#x21b1;
\upuparrows          = ⇈  or  &#x21c8;
\downdownarrows      = ⇊  or  &#x21ca;
\upharpoonleft       = ↿  or  &#x21bf;
\upharpoonright      = ↾  or  &#x21be;
\downharpoonleft     = ⇃  or  &#x21c3;
\restriction         = ↾  or  &#x21be;
\multimap            = ⊸  or  &#x22b8;
\downharpoonright    = ⇂  or  &#x21c2;
\leftrightsquigarrow = ↭  or  &#x21ad;
\rightsquigarrow     = ⇝  or  &#x21dd;
\leadsto             = ⇝  or  &#x21dd;
\dashrightarrow      = ⇢  or  &#x21e2;
\dashleftarrow       = ⇠  or  &#x21e0;

\nleftarrow      = ↚  or  &#219a;
\nrightarrow     = ↛  or  &#219b;
\nLeftarrow      = ⇍  or  &#21cd;
\nRightarrow     = ⇏  or  &#21cf;
\nleftrightarrow = ↮  or  &#21ae;
\nLeftrightarrow = ⇎  or  &#21ce;

\ulcorner = ┌  or  &#x250c;
\urcorner = ┐  or  &#x2510;
\llcorner = └  or  &#x2514;
\lrcorner = ┘  or  &#x2518;

\implies   = \;\Longrightarrow\;
\impliedby = \;\Longleftarrow\;
```