# Please enable AMSsymbols extension for MathJax

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

Please enable the AMSsymbols extensionfor MathJax. The lack of this extension has led to several independent bug reports.

- [The \not\mid symbol is not working well](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/the-not-mid-symbol-is-not-working-well)
- [Tex \implies symbol does not work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/tex-implies-symbol-does-not-work)
- [TeX beth symbol missing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/tex-beth-symbol-missing-closed)
- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/971/revisions

More independent bug reports (everyone, please feel free to add them if/when you can edit this post):

- [Command for strict inclusion does not render](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/command-for-strict-inclusion-does-not-render)

Comment: The fourth link you included is to a thread on the 404 error page, is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Dear Carl, you do know that \Rightarrow (or one of its lengthened varieties) gives \implies, right?

Comment: @Willie: I was the one who made that post. I had wanted to use the $\nexists$ symbol, which renders slightly better than $\not\exists$. KennyTM helpfully edited my post to fix it, but that means one has to link to the revision history to see evidence of the problem.

Comment: @97832123: actually I ran into this problem with the Hebrew letter beth. For random newcomers, having the macros available would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @KennyTM: why did you remove the "bug" tag from this post? It's clearly a bug - the symbols that numerous people expect to work don't work. Apart from that - is there any specific tag that flags the post to get the attention of the people who can activate the extension?

Comment: @Carl: A bug is some wrong outcome that is not what the *designer* expected, therefore they can be denied by `[status-bydesign]`. So far this is clearly by-design as extensions are not turned on before we request it. A feature-request is some desired outcome that (most of) *you* want to be. A feature-request doesn't mean it is less important than a bug.

Comment: @Carl: The `[tex]` tag should be sufficient.

Comment: Can we get a timeline on a response to this?  Recently I've been rather discouraged by the response of site administrators: from my perspective, it seems that almost all of their intervention has been negative.  (I was especially distressed by the locking of a thread that detailed a very reasonable complaint.)  This should be an easy opportunity to improve morale...

Comment: @KennyTM: "A feature-request doesn't mean it is less important than a bug." Perhaps not, but I'm pretty sure it gets less *priority* than a bug.

Comment: @Rahul: One's priority **does not** affect the *nature* of the issue.

Comment: @KennyTM: Fair enough. I still feel ought to be a distinction between the "It would be nice if I had a pony"-style *feature requests*, and "The product is working as designed, but *there is something wrong with the design* " issues. I would consider that sort of thing a *bug* in the very *design*. But there's no way to express that, so I suppose [feature-request] will have to do.

Answer (score 12):

We have enabled the AMSsymbols extension - this will be deployed with our build later today.

Comment: Very awesome. I guess wishes do come true...

Comment: @j.m. http://imgur.com/gnqJW.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Thank you, Geoff, for doing this.

Comment: To repeat Nuno and Pete: thank you.