# Command for strict inclusion does not render

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please enable AMSsymbols extension for MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/please-enable-amssymbols-extension-for-mathjax)

I typed the command \subsetneq in an answer a few moments ago and it didn't  render : the output just reproduced the command in red.  I also tried \subsetneqq, \varsubsetneq and \varsubsetneqq, but to no avail. Finally I  resorted to the clumsy parenthetical remark "strict inclusion".
Could some maven please explain what I should do? (I apologize if this question has already been asked.)

Comment: This is almost surely a sub-case of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/please-enable-amssymbols-extension-for-mathjax

Comment: @Willie: I would have assumed as much, but [MathJax apparently just doesn't support the subsetneq symbol at all](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). The only workaround would be to use the Unicode symbol directly. Testing: $A ⊊ B$ (copy-pasted from [here](http://unicodeforyou.appspot.com/subset%20not%20equal))

Comment: Scratch that, it works on MathOverflow. I suppose MathJax's documentation is incomplete.

Comment: This is ***not*** an exact duplicate.